# PyInstaller: Executable to access user-specified Sourcecode

Tags: python, import, user-defined-functions

I'm using pyinstaller to distribute my code as executable within my team as most of them are not coding/scripting people and do not have Python Interpreter installed.

For some advanced usage of my tool, I want to make it possible for the user to implement a small custom function to adjust functionality slightly (for the few experienced people). Hence I want to let them input a python file which defines a function with a fixed name and a string as return.

Is that possible?
I mean the py-file could be drag/dropped for example, and I'd tell them that their user-defined function needs to have a certain name, e.g. "analyze()" - is it now possible to import that from the drag/dropped pythonfile within my PyInstaller Script and use it as this?

I know, it certainly will not be safe/secure and they could do evil things, delete files and so one... But that are things which we don#t care at this point, please no discussions about it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question: yes it does actually work to import a module/function from a given path/pythonfile at runtime (that I knew already) even in PyInstaller (that was new for me).

I used this for my Py2.7 program:

```
f = r'C:\path\to\userdefined\filewithfunction.py'
if os.path.exists(f):
    import imp
    userdefined = imp.load_source('', f) # Only Python 2.x, for 3.x see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67692/701049
    print userdefined   # just a debugging print
    userdefined.imported()  # here you should use try/catch; or check whether the function with the desired name really exists in the object "userdefined". This is only a small demo as example how to import, so didnt do it here.



filewithfunction.py:
--------------------
def imported():
    print 'yes it worked :-)'
```

As written in the comments of the example code, you'll need a slightly different approach in Python 3.x. See this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67692/701049